# N x N identity matrix in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I am having difficulty creating a generic N x N identity matrix in Matlab.

I am given a system where

```
Ai,j =

{1, if i does not equal j

{n, if i = j}
```

You are asked to compute this when the value of the identity matrix n = 10, n = 20.

What I don't see is how to apply matrix indexing here. That is easy enough to do, but how do I account for the given linear system?

Comment: Try `eye(n) * (n-1) + 1`

Comment: @rahnema1 makes sense. so when n = 10, youll have I=eye(10) . * (10-1)+1 and for n = 20 similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function for creating a unit matrix called `eye`.

have a look at the documentation http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html?requestedDomain=au.mathworks.com

Also, `ones(n,m)` creates a matrix of ones.

For a square matrix use `(n-1)*eye(n) + ones(n)` and for non-square 
`(n-1)*eye(n, m) + ones(n, m)`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But what about the given system of equations? How would you account for that?